# Should we have a swarm-robotics tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

**Should we have a swarm-robotics tag?**

[What weapons would nanomachines use?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/139180/what-weapons-would-nanomachines-use)

I mean, it largely differs from robotics (especially thanks to its unique challenges), then I realized we don't even have a robotics tag.

Comment: Robotics tag would definitely be helpful, but there might not be enough questions about swarm robots to justify a tag for it.

Comment: @JohnLocke I'm sure nanomachines would often involve it, though, and there are quite a few of those questions lying around.

Comment: Note that nanomachines and swarm-robotics are not quite related. It is like claiming that electric engines and to-scale model trains should be in the same category.

Answer (score 3):

A tag should be widely enough applicable that we can envision a reasonable number of on-topic questions that would benefit from it for categorization purposes.

The best way to demonstrate this is to point to several questions that you feel would benefit from the tag. In this case, one is none.

Also, the tag must not be a duplicate of an existing tag. (Specializations is another matter, like we have [mythical-creatures](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mythical-creatures) but also [centaur](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/centaur) or [unicorns](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/unicorns), for example. I'm not always happy about those, but at least one is generally pretty clearly a subset of the other.) If a tag is hard to find, we should consider renaming or synonymizing it, rather than creating another tag.

While it is true that invoking extremely small machines ([nanotechnology](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nanotechnology)) poses somewhat unique challenges, and that what they use for [weapons](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/weapons) may therefore differ from that used by larger entities for similar purposes, I'm not sure you have sufficiently demonstrated:

- that there is a need to separately categorize questions on *swarm* robotics, as opposed to plain [robots](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/robots) with further clarification in the question title or early in the question text
- that there is a huge difference between weapons that would be useful to [nanotechnology](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nanotechnology) as opposed to those useful to very small [fauna](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fauna), regardless of whether the individual entities are solitary or cooperative
- that [nanotechnology](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nanotechnology) by necessity involves machines working together in a swarm
- that machines working together in a swarm would necessarily be [nanotechnology](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nanotechnology)
- that very small [robots](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/robots) wouldn't be using something that can be categorized as small [weapons](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/weapons)
- that very small [weapons](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/weapons) couldn't be categorized as a combination of, say, [nanotechnology](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nanotechnology) and [weapons](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/weapons)

For the time being, I think that **the case is not compelling** for a swarm-robotics tag.